# Android application exists and display an error `Unfortunately, TestGPS has stopped`

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-gps

I'm new to android and when I googled my issue I couldn't find a proper solution to my problem.

I'm trying to develop a location based android app that can find user location automatically. My code compiles without any error in android studio manager, but when I click on `Show Location` button, my application exists and display an error `Unfortunately, TestGPS has stopped`[image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lsdias.testgps" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".GPSTracker"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

GPSTracker.java

```
package com.example.lsdias.testgps;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPSTracker extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener
{
    Button btnShowLocation;
    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker()
    {
        mContext = null;
    }

    public GPSTracker(Context mContext)
    {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation()
    {
        try
        {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                // no network provider is enabled
            }
            else
            {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled)
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null)
                    {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null)
                        {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled)
                {
                    if (location == null)
                    {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null)
                        {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null)
                            {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpstracker);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Location);

        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(canGetLocation())
                {
                    double latitude = getLatitude();
                    double longitude = getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_gpstracker, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check if best network provider
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }
}
```

logcat

```
09-02 12:47:51.902    1935-1935/com.example.lsdias.testgps I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-02 12:47:52.384    1935-1958/com.example.lsdias.testgps D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
09-02 12:47:52.385    1935-1935/com.example.lsdias.testgps D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c40550, tid 1935
09-02 12:47:52.418    1935-1935/com.example.lsdias.testgps D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
09-02 12:47:52.582    1935-1949/com.example.lsdias.testgps I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4140(288KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 28% free, 810KB/1135KB, paused 61.733ms total 123.372ms
09-02 12:47:52.607    1935-1958/com.example.lsdias.testgps D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c406b0, tid 1958
09-02 12:47:52.675    1935-1958/com.example.lsdias.testgps I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-02 12:47:52.697    1935-1958/com.example.lsdias.testgps D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-02 12:47:52.764    1935-1958/com.example.lsdias.testgps W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-02 12:47:52.764    1935-1958/com.example.lsdias.testgps W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c1ae20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-02 12:47:53.478    1935-1958/com.example.lsdias.testgps W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-02 12:47:53.478    1935-1958/com.example.lsdias.testgps W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c1ae20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-02 12:47:58.675    1935-1935/com.example.lsdias.testgps D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
09-02 12:47:58.675    1935-1935/com.example.lsdias.testgps E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lsdias.testgps, PID: 1935
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:154)
            at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:379)
            at com.example.lsdias.testgps.GPSTracker.showSettingsAlert(GPSTracker.java:240)
            at com.example.lsdias.testgps.GPSTracker$1.onClick(GPSTracker.java:155)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: As your logCat shows, problem is in your showSettingsAlert() function. Try replacing `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);` with `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());`.

Comment: or onCreate set mContext = getApplicationContext()

Comment: don't merge GPSTracker class and your Activity, simple way to do is Separate GpsTracker.java and Activty, In your Activity-onCreate() create instance of GpsTracker and pass context, and finally in your onClick() called Location location = gpsTrackerInstance.getLocation();

Comment: @lawstud does not work, same issue

Comment: @tony not working, same issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `mContext` in `GPSTracker` is `null`, and you are creating `AlertDialog` with null `Context`.
Also you should not override Activity's constructors. 
Move your `getLocation();` into `onCreate()` method

Comment: since `mContext` is a private final variable I have defined it in a constructor. Can you explain how to solve this?

Comment: @LalindaSampath, that depends on how you use `GPSTracker`

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'mContext' is defined final and it not have been initialized.I don't think the code compiles without any error in android studio. You needn't make mContext final, and should initialize in onCreate() method. If you just want mContext final, see this:

```
private final Context mContext = this;
```